# How to switch sorting order in TreeSet

Tags: java

I have a custom class where I have implemented both `Comparable` and `Comparator` interface. The sorting/comparison logic is opposite for the two.

consider the below class as an example:

```
class Test implements Comparable<Test>, Comparator<Test>{
    private Integer field;
    public Test(Integer field){this.field = field;}
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Test obj){
       return this.field.compareTo(obj.field);
    }
    @Override
    public int compare(Test t1, Test t2){
       return -t1.compareTo(t2);
    }
    //impl of equals, hashCode and toString omitted for this example
}
```

So when I add objects of `Test` to a `TreeSet` by default it is sorting by the implementation of the `Comparable` which is understood as per the JDK source. So is there any flag/switch to switch to the sorting represented by the `Comparable` implementation? 
I do not want to pass another `Comparator` to the `TreeSet` constructor.

Comment: A class shouldn't implement both `Comparable` and `Comparator`: either it's a thing which you can compare, or it's a thing you can use to compare things.

Comment: If your class already is comparable, `new TreeSet(Comparator.reverseOrder())` should do the trick, or `new TreeSet(new Test())` using the "reverse" comparator in your class (which IMHO is a very terrible idea to have)

Comment: "I do not want to pass another Comparator to the TreeSet constructor." Why? That is _exactly_ how you are supposed to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a misconception on your side:

- A `Comparable` class has objects that can be compared against each other (for example by a container that wants to sort them
- A `Comparator` is the thing that compares two objects of some class.

There is no need for you to make your class implement **both**.

And worse: remember that code communicates intent: the idea that your class implements **both** interfaces, but in "opposite" ways, that is very much **counter intuitive**. It will simply confuse your readers, and can lead to all kinds of bugs, just because your code does something that few experienced java developers would expect it to do. Never write code that surprises your readers (in a bad way).

Instead note that you can simply create a TreeSet using `Collections.reverseOrder()` for example! In other words: the fact that you defined how to compare two objects of `Test` allows you to use a default [(reversing)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder--) comparator already.

Long story short: avoid "inventing" "clever" tricks to work around framework behavior. Instead, learn how the framework "ticks", and adapt to that. Don't fight the tide, flow with it.

Comment: @tobias_k True. That alone is worth another paragraph that I just added.

Comment: So ideally we should keep custom comparators outside the pojos?

Comment: We could also keep them inside a static nested class?

Comment: @AmitSah I wouldn't make the class itself the Comparator. Where *else* to keep them, that is a matter of "taste" respectively: your "best practice". When your team puts such things into more central utility classes, then do that. If your team prefers static nested classes, go for that. There is no universal rules that mandates the "best" solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same object as both `Comparator` and `Comparable` is quite atypical. You can achieve both sort orders using just one of the two interfaces.

With just `Comparator`:

```
//Test implements Comparator. reversed() changes order
new TreeSet(new Test().reversed());
```

With just `Comparable`:

```
 //elements are Comparable. reverseOrder changes order
new TreeSet(Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Comparator.comparingInt(Test::getField).reversed())` then you don't need to implement your own comparation methods to the Test class.

**Full example code:**

```
static class Test {
    private int field;

    public Test(int field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    public int getField() {
        return field;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test = new Test(5);
    Test test2 = new Test(8);
    TreeSet<Test> tests = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingInt(Test::getField).reversed());
    tests.add(test);
    tests.add(test2);
    for (Test t:tests)
      System.out.println(t.getField());
}
```

**Outputs:**

```
8
5
```